# Magento 2: How to get Post data in backend/adminhtml?

Tags: magento2, post-data

I have added a massaction to the sales order grid in Magento 2. I want to pass on the POST data (the checked orders) to my custom controller/page which is setup and working as expected.

How do I retrieve the POST data in my controller or on the page. I searched allot but cannot find tutorials or examples. I know i can do `$this->getRequest()->getPost()`. But that only applies when the action is extending `Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action` but as far as I know this is only for frontend actions. My class is extending `\Magento\Backend\App\Action` as it needs to be a backend action.

Any extensive documentation or other resources on this topic would also be great!

**EDIT:** This was follow up question in looking for an answer. It might help users with the same problem: [Magento 2 how to pass order id's from sales order grid to my module controller](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96627/magento-2-how-to-pass-order-ids-from-sales-order-grid-to-my-module-controller)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$this->getRequest()->getParams();` will get you the post data. If you want to access a specific parameter you can use `$this->getRequest()->getParam('something');` I have tested this on an admin controller and it will work when extending `\Magento\Backend\App\Action`

Comment: Thanks, this is working indeed. Altough I was expecting data from the sales grid checkboxes. Am I think wrong? How can I retrieve the checked order id's?

Comment: You must be sending the wrong payload. You're controller will only receive the data you send it. If you are sending post data from a form, your controller will receive the value of each input in the form being submitted. I haven't done much with grids yet so I'm not sure what the fields are.

Comment: Can you guide me with a more extensive approach/answer? I don't know how to get the checked order id's into my own extension.