# Magento 2 how to pass order id's from sales order grid to my module controller

Tags: magento2, massaction, post-data, order-grid

I am working on a custom module. I need order data in my own controller. I want users to use the checkboxes to select orders so i can use the order id's/data in my controller. How do I do this?

What I have done so far:

1. Make module
2. Add massaction with custom url to the sales order grid
3. Setup routing for my custom url
4. Created controller so my custom url works

I don't know how I can get the selected order id's in my controller. I asked this: [Magento 2: How to get Post data in backend/adminhtml?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96578/magento-2-how-to-get-post-data-in-backend-adminhtml) But the POST Data doesn't contain the order id's.

How can I proceed? What is the next step? And how do I achieve that?

Comment: Hello , Get ids using Custom Mass Action.

Answer (score 3):

`\Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter::getCollection` is responsible for adding filter criteria to your collection and you can iterate through it to do some mass action. It will obtain \Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter::(SELECTED|EXCLUDED)_PARAM param from request and use it as filter for collection.
See `\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\MassDelete` for example.

Comment: Thanks, how can I implement this? I am new to Magento 2. A tutorial or guide with explanaition would be awesome. I couldn't find any sepcific for this task.

Answer (score 1):

To complete @KAndy answer, as of magento 2.2 (not tested on previous version), you can't get ids from request. You must use \Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter::getCollection to getAllIds.

Here a full example :

In your ui_component : (ex : routefrontendname_index_listing.xml)

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
...
  <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
...
    <massaction name="listing_massaction" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions">
      <action name="delete">
        <settings>
          <confirm>
            <message translate="true">Are you sure you want to delete selected items?</message>
            <title translate="true">Delete items</title>
          </confirm>
          <url path="routeFrontendName/index/massDelete"/>
          <type>delete</type>
          <label translate="true">Delete</label>
        </settings>
      </action>
    </massaction>
...

  </listingToolbar>
...
</listing>
```

Controller MassDelete :

```
    <?php



namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use \Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use \Vendor\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\YourModel\CollectionFactory;
use \Vendor\ModuleName\Model\YourModelRepository;


class MassDelete extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var Filter
     */
    protected $filter;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $collectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var YourModelRepository
     */
    protected $yourModelRepository;

    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        Filter $filter,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        YourModelRepository $yourModelRepository
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->filter = $filter;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->yourModelRepository = $yourModelRepository;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $collection = $this->filter->getCollection($this->collectionFactory->create());
        try {
            $entityDeleted = 0;
            foreach ($collection->getAllIds() as $id) {
                $this->yourModelRepository->deleteById($id);
                $entityDeleted++;
            }
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('A total of %1 record(s) were deleted.', $entityDeleted));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__($e->getMessage()));
        }

        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/index', array('_current' => true));
    }
}
```