# Magento2 Cannot pass data into form

Tags: magento2

I have Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Controller/Adminhtml/Post/Edit.php

```
<?php

namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\Post;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\PostFactory;

class Edit extends Action
{
/**
 * @var Registry
 */
protected $_coreRegistry = null;

/**
 * @var PageFactory
 */
protected $resultPageFactory;

/**
 * @var PostFactory
 */
protected $_post;

public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    Registry $registry,
    PostFactory $post
) {
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
    $this->_post = $post;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Mageplaza_HelloWorld::index');
}

public function execute()
{
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('post_id');

    $post = $this->_post->create();

    if ($id) {
        $post->load($id);

        if (!$post->getId()) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('This record no longer exists.'));
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        }
    }

    $data = $this->_session->getFormData(true);

    if (!empty($data)) {
        $post->addData($data);
    }

    $this->_coreRegistry->register('post_id', $id);

    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend((__('Posts')));
    return $resultPage;
}
```

}

And i have Mageplaza/HelloWorld/view/adminthml/ui_component/mageplaza_helloworld_post_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">mageplaza_helloworld_post_form.mageplaza_helloworld_post_form_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">mageplaza_helloworld_post_form.mageplaza_helloworld_post_form_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
    </item>
    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Post CRUD</item>
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="back" xsi:type="string">Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Adminhtml\Post\Edit\BackButton</item>
        <item name="reset" xsi:type="string">Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Adminhtml\Post\Edit\ResetButton</item>
        <item name="delete" xsi:type="string">Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Adminhtml\Post\Edit\DeleteButton</item>
        <item name="save" xsi:type="string">Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Adminhtml\Post\Edit\SaveButton</item>
    </item>
</argument>
<dataSource name="mageplaza_helloworld_post_form_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">mageplaza_helloworld_post_form_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">post_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">post_id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/save"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
<fieldset name="main_fieldset">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">General</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <field name="post_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">post_id</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">post_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>

    <field name="name">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Name</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">name</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">name</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>

    <field name="url_key">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Url Key</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">url_key</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">url_key</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>

    <field name="post_content">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Post content</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">post_content</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">post_content</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>

    <field name="tags">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Tag</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">tags</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">tags</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>

    <field name="status" formElement="select">
        <settings>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Status</label>
            <source>status</source>
            <dataScope>status</dataScope>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <select>
                <settings>
                    <options>
                        <option name="Enable" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Enable</item>
                        </option>
                        <option name="Disable" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Disable</item>
                        </option>
                    </options>
                    <caption translate="true">-- Please Select --</caption>
                </settings>
            </select>
        </formElements>
    </field>

    <field name="test">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Test</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">test</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">test</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>

    <field name="featured_image">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Featured Image</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">featured_image</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">featured_image</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>

    <field name="created_at">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Create Date</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">21</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">created_at</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">created_at</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
                <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
                    <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">HH:mm:ss</item>
                    <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>

    <field name="updated_at">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Update Date</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">21</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">updated_at</item>
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">updated_at</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
                <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
                    <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">HH:mm:ss</item>
                    <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>       

</fieldset>
```

When i click edit button i selected id and array data. But form edit no data received. Please help me

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/96581/85907

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

> Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Controller/Adminhtml/Post/Edit.php

```
<?php

namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Adminhtml\Post;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

class Edit extends Action
{

    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        // 1. Get ID and create model
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('post_id');
        $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\Post');

        // 2. Initial checking
        if ($id) {
            $model->load($id);
            if (!$model->getId()) {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('This record no longer exists.'));
                /** \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
                $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();

                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            }
        }

        // 3. Set entered data if was error when we do save
        $data = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->getFormData(true);
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $model->setData($data);
        }

        // 4. Register model to use later in blocks
        $this->_coreRegistry->register('post_id', $model);

        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend((__('Post')));

        return $resultPage;

    }
}
```

> Mageplaza/HelloWorld/view/adminthml/ui_component/mageplaza_helloworld_post_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">mageplaza_helloworld_post_form.mageplaza_helloworld_post_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">mageplaza_helloworld_post_form.mageplaza_helloworld_post_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Post CRUD</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="back" xsi:type="string">Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Adminhtml\Post\Edit\BackButton</item>
            <item name="reset" xsi:type="string">Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Adminhtml\Post\Edit\ResetButton</item>
            <item name="delete" xsi:type="string">Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Adminhtml\Post\Edit\DeleteButton</item>
            <item name="save" xsi:type="string">Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Adminhtml\Post\Edit\SaveButton</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="mageplaza_helloworld_post_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">
                Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\Post\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">mageplaza_helloworld_post_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">post_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">post_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/save"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="main_fieldset">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">General</item>
            </item>
        </argument>

        <field name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Name</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">postdata</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="url_key">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Url Key</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">postdata</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">url_key</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="post_content">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Post content</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">postdata</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">post_content</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="tags">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Tag</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">postdata</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">tags</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Model\Source\Status</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">postdata</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">status</item>
                    <item name="caption" xsi:type="string" translate="true"> Please Select </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="featured_image">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Featured Image</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">postdata</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">featured_image</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="created_at">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Create Date</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">21</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">postdata</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">created_at</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
                        <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">HH:mm:ss</item>
                        <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <field name="updated_at">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Update Date</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">21</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">postdata</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">updated_at</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yyyy-MM-dd</item>
                        <item name="timeFormat" xsi:type="string">HH:mm:ss</item>
                        <item name="showsTime" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>       

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Useful Links**

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-form.html

http://techjeffyu.com/blog/magento-2-create-uicomponent-list-and-uicomponent-form-by-example

Comment: Thank you verymuch devidas!

Comment: Welcome @HưngNguyễn